# Bootstrap dynamic height container with text input at the bottom of the container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4. I'm trying to create a desktop chatbot similar to Google's Bard. This will be using a container that is the height of the screen with the text input at the bottom of the container. The container will also have a scrollbar when user inputs and responses get too large for the container but the text input will always be at the bottom.

I've tried this:

```css
.col-md-9 {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  align-items: flex-end;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.full-page {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: justify;">

    The UK Supreme Court has been hearing an appeal from PACCAR Inc and others against the Competition Appeal Tribunal and others. The case revolves around the legality and effectiveness of third-party litigation funding arrangements. The key issue is the
    interpretation of a statutory definition, specifically whether litigation funding agreements (LFAs) that entitle the funder to a percentage of any

    <div class="container-fluid border pt-3" style="full-page">
      <pre><div id="result"></div></pre>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <textarea id="input_text" name="input_text" placeholder="Enter a prompt here"></textarea>
        <br />

        <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" name="submit-btn" value="{{ summary['id'] }}" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
      <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" id="spinner" style="display: none"></span>
      
      Submit</button>
      </div>

      <br><br><br>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried using `<div class="fixed-bottom">...</div>` but this does the input text end-to-end of the screen. I could use this but how would I customise it? I'm reall just trying to replicate bard

[image: screenshot of Bard and what i'm trying to achieve]

My issues so far:

1. The container is not expanding to the height of the screen.
2. I can't get the text input to be at the bottom of the container with a width equal to the container.

Comment: Adding a bit more clarity as to what you're after would help in answering the question. Currently I'm not sure what specifically you're trying to change or what the issue you're having is.

Comment: Sorry. My issues so far: 1. The container is not expanding to the height of the screen. 2. I can't get the text input to be at the bottom of the container with a width equal to the container. I will edit the original post

Answer (score 1):

You're currently calling the 'full-page' class in the style attribute. If you move this class over to the class attribute on the div element, you'll be able to see the class styling take affect.

```css
.col-md-9 {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
    bottom: 0;
  position: sticky;
  height: 50px;
  top: calc(100% - 50px);
  align-items: flex-end;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

}

.full-page {
  height: 90vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: justify;">

      The UK Supreme Court has been hearing an appeal from PACCAR Inc and others against the Competition Appeal Tribunal and others. The case revolves around the legality and effectiveness of third-party litigation funding arrangements. The key issue is the
      interpretation of a statutory definition, specifically whether litigation funding agreements (LFAs) that entitle the funder to a percentage of any

      <div class="container-fluid border pt-3 full-page">
        <pre><div id="result"></div></pre>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <textarea id="input_text" name="input_text" placeholder="Enter a prompt here"></textarea>
          <br />

          <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" name="submit-btn" value="{{ summary['id'] }}" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
      <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" id="spinner" style="display: none"></span>
      
      Submit</button>
        </div>

        <br><br><br>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

I've updated my the code to help you with what you're struggling with in the comment you added. By adding position:sticky instead of absolute; then you can have the page be whatever height you want and you can still have the input at the bottom of the page.

Comment: thanks! that makes a difference but now the container overshoots the page as opposed to just the height of the page. Any ideas? Also, how do i get the input fied at the bottom of the container?

Comment: I just updated the answer to hopefully better assist you with these two other requests.